# Function containing invalid characters in its name

Tags: javascript, function, global, window-object

I was trying to abuse function names in Chrome dev tools:

```
window["hello world"] = function () { console.log("Hello World!"); }
```

The line above will create `hello world` global function.

It appears in autocomplete suggestions also:

> [image]

If we call it this way (`hello world()`) we get a syntax error, that is supposed to be so:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

However, how can we call this function without using quotes (`window["hello world"]()`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given the function a name at all. It is an anonymous function that is assigned to a property of the `window` object.

Since the property name has spaces in it, you can't access it using an identifier, so **the only way** to get to it is to explicitly use the window object.

```
window["hello world"]();
```

---

If you really want to run the function *without using quotes*, then you can do the following. Note that this is a perverse hack and not something that you should do in production code.

```
window["hello world"] = function () { console.log("Hello World!"); }
// No quotes for any of the code used to access the above.
window[
    [ 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100 ].map(
        function (currentValue) {
            return String.fromCharCode(currentValue);
        }
    ).join(new String)
]();
```

Comment: Great idea. :-) *Note that this is a perverse hack and not something that you should do in production code.* -- for sure, everything was more or less a joke, just to find the limits of such property names.